# ANTLR4: Whitespace handling

Tags: parsing, antlr, whitespace, parser-generator, antlr4

I have seen many ANTLR grammars that use whitespace handling like this:

```
WS: [ \n\t\r]+ -> skip;
// or
WS: [ \n\t\r]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

So the whitespaces are thrown away respectively send to the hidden channel.

With a grammar like this:

```
grammar Not;

start:      expression;
expression: NOT expression
          | (TRUE | FALSE);

NOT:    'not';
TRUE:   'true';
FALSE:  'false';
WS: [ \n\t\r]+ -> skip;
```

valid inputs are '*not true*' or '*not false*' but also '*nottrue*' which is not a desired result.
Changing the grammar to:

```
grammar Not;

start:      expression;

expression: NOT WS+ expression
          | (TRUE | FALSE);

NOT:    'not';

TRUE:   'true';
FALSE:  'false';

WS: [ \n\t\r];
```

fixes the problem, but i do not want to handle the whitespaces manually in each rule.

Generally i want to have a whitespace between each token with some exceptions (e.g. '*!true*' does not need a whitespace in between).

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add an `IDENTIFIER` lexer rule to handle words which are not keywords.

```
IDENTIFIER : [a-zA-Z]+;
```

Now the text `nottrue` is a single `IDENTIFIER` token which your parser would not accept in place of the distinct keywords in `not true`.

Make sure `IDENTIFIER` is defined *after* your other keywords. The lexer will find that both `NOT` and `IDENTIFIER` match the text `not`, and will assign the token type to the first one that appears in the grammar.

Comment: Thanks. That works as desired for '*nottrue*' (invalid) and '*!true*' (valid). Do you also have an idea how i can make an exception of this rule, so that it is possible for some other inputs to omit the whitespace? Like '*A B true*', where the whitespace between A and B is optional. So this is also valid: '*AB true*', but '*ABtrue*' not.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to control how whitespace is handled then the most strightforward way is to give instructions to antlr how to handle whitespace. Eg. WS+
Why should antlr be able to automatically guess how you want the whitespace to be handled without specifying it explicitly?